# Is there a word that means "multiply by ten"?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, phrase-requests, connotation

I'm wondering if there is a word that means to 'multiply by ten'.

I'm curious based on my interest in the word *decimate,* which used to mean to remove a tenth of something.

Comment: True, but it comes from a word that means just that. Of course, using it in that sense in a mathematical context might sound bizarre!

Comment: @JimiOke - Actually, the word means "kill 10%".

Comment: @HotLicks: I am not unfamiliar with the archaic meaning as in to kill one in every ten. I said the origin of *decimate* is from the Latin *decimus*, which means *tenth*, or *decimat-* (*taken as a tenth*).

Comment: @MrLister: We definitely don't have to split hairs here, but taking a tenth of something essentially implies a division of sorts (not literal but a division nonetheless in the mathematical sense)...

Comment: @JimiOke:   Then don't split hairs.   The division you're talking about is division but 10/9.   No one in a linguistic context would call that "division of sorts" even if it's mathematically true.    Does the verb "to double" imply "a division of sorts" (by 0.5)?   Does "to leave unchanged" imply a division by 1?

Comment: @Kundor Whoops, put the wrong name there, good catch.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Since you want to split hairs: In order to remove a 10th of something, you need to determine how much that is. This requires division.

Comment: @DCShannon: You count to ten.  Then push that individual off the cliff.  Continue, restarting counting from one.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: Right, which is precisely what he's been saying the whole time, and the reason the question is now fixed.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - The original question, before the OP edited it in response to my comment, said, "I know that decimate used to mean essentially dividing by ten".

Comment: @DCShannon - no, to remove one tenth, you would multiply by 0.9.

Comment: "Decimate" is about counting, not measuring.
So we're looking for a word that can be applied to a number, not just a quantity.  "Twice as many" not "twice as much".   Double, triple, quadruple.  "Tenfold" is great, but doesn't QUITE answer the question.

Comment: I'd prefer to not choose a correct answer, because both Jimi Oke's and SamuelVimes' answers are exceptional.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

That word is *[decuple](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/decuple)* (Collins Dictionary):

> **verb**
>
> (transitive) to increase by ten times

It can also be used as a noun or adjective.

Comment: Problem is, it sounds like "de-couple". Not that we can do anything about it.

Comment: While this is true; this word is extremely uncommon in use to the extent that I think it unlikely that the asker's audience would understand the meaning.

Comment: @JackAidley: To be fair the OP provided no context, simply asking for *a word* that meant *multiply by ten*, hence my answer. Of course this is an obscure word I've never heard or seen in writing!

Comment: @Lohoris: Actually the stress is on the first syllable (as in *decimal* or *quadruple*), so it really doesn't quite sound like *decouple* :)

Comment: This is the item in the list starting "double, triple, quadruple, quintuple, ..."  So a mathematician might say "10-tuple".

Comment: Yeah - *n-tuple* is common in academic papers.

Comment: @JimiOke In my experience (American English), the stress in quadruple, quintuple, etc., is on the second syllable.  However, arguably this word should be pronounced "deh-COO-pull", rather than "dee-CUP-uhl."

Comment: @ChrisSunami: You're right. The second-syllable stress on the *-uple*'s is more common in American English, while the first- is more common in *BrE*. In the Collins dictionary, both stress patterns are shown, but for *decuple*, only the first-syllable pronunciation is provided. I imagine the word was never used in America then! (tongue-in-cheek comment!)

Comment: @JimiOke: As a native English speaker, I have _never_ heard the stress placed on the first syllable. That would sound quite strange.

Comment: I'm a native speaker too. *QUAdruple* is just as valid as *quaDRUple*. Guess it depends on where one grows up or those one tends to have in conversation.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit However, one should really stress the dec part of decuple. Compare this to decimal, also relates to '10-', I don't think American people pronounce DEC-si-mal as dec-SI-mal do they?

Comment: @MobiusPizza: That's not really the point. You don't say DEC-athlon. The fact that ten is involved does not define the stress.

Comment: Since there seems to be a lot of hair splitting on this page... ;-), I think that Collins should say "*to increase by* ***nine*** *times*", if the aim is to multiply by ten. E.g., 3 + (3 x 9) = 30 = 3 x 10. Of course, one can argue about just what "*increase by N times*" means. To me, it means to add a quantity that is ten times the original: 3 + (3 x 10) = 33. But compare [other dictionaries](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=decuple+definition), some of which say the same thing as Collins. At the very least, they should probably use another expression than "*increase by N times*".

Comment: @Drew: Excellent hair-splitting point!

Answer (score 58):

I think that the word you may be looking for could be ***tenfold.*** According to Collins (http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tenfold):

> adjective:
>
> 1. equal to or having 10 times as many or as much   ⇒ "a tenfold increase in population"
> 2. composed of 10 parts
>
> adverb:
>
> 1. by or up to 10 times as many or as much   ⇒ "the population increased tenfold"

Regarding the etimology, according to Etymonline (http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=tenfold):

> ***tenfold*** (adj.) 
>       Old English tienfeald; see ten + -fold. As an adverb in modern use from 1530s.

And also from Etymonline (http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-fold&allowed_in_frame=0):

> ***-fold***
>       Multiplicative word-forming element attached to numerals, from Old English -feald, Northumbrian -fald, from Proto-Germanic *-falthaz (cognates: Old Saxon -fald, Old Frisian -fald, Old Norse -faldr, Dutch -voud, German -falt, Gothic falþs), comb. form of *falthan, from PIE *polt-, extended form of root *pel- (3) "to fold" (cognates: Greek -paltos, -plos; Latin -plus; see fold (v.)). Native words with it have been crowded out by Latinate double, triple, etc., but it persists in manifold, hundredfold, etc.

Some examples of use:

> *"The annual crop of wheat in the regency, is estimated at 7,200,000 bushels and with the proper cultivation might be tenfolded"*
>
> From "A compendious and complete system of modern geography: or, A view of the world" by Jeddediah Morse (1812)

Another example of use:

> *"It is nice to dream about tenfolding one's money in a year and a half"*
>
> From "The Zurich Axioms" by Max Gunther (2005)

Comment: [From](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/decuple) Late Latin decuplus (“tenfold”), from Latin decem (“ten”), and plico (“fold”). English is flexible, so it could be verbed; +1.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the word the OP was looking for, plus *tenfold* is not quite a verb. (By the way I didn't downvote this answer!)

Comment: @CeesTimmerman: I agree English is flexible... but *tenfold* used as a transitive verb might immediately conjure up the image of folding something ten times over or in ten places (which is also essentially a form of multiplication but not in the expected sense)!

Comment: @JimiOke Apologies, I missed that

Comment: @DoubleDouble: no worries. I'm also prone to arguing for better or worse. But this question has sparked so many spirited conversations!

Comment: Correct, the German word for it is: "zehnfach"

Comment: Let's go with *tenfoldify*!

Answer (score 35):

### Increase by an order of magnitude

In plain English, if you multiply something by 10, you have [increased its order of magnitude](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37244/meaning-of-one-order-of-magnitude-improvement) by one.

More technically, when using the base 10 number system, all numbers can be written in exponential form, such as 1.984 x 10<sup>3</sup>, and [if you multiply by ten you merely increment the exponent by one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_magnitude): 1.984 x 10<sup>4</sup>. Therefore, the order of magnitude is dependent on your base and on whether your scale is linear, logarithmic, or something else.

### Decimate

Decimate is currently shifting its meaning. The original sense of the word was to [kill 10% of a group of people.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimation_%28Roman_army%29) Mercifully, that practice was almost completely abandoned 2000 years ago. Therefore, most people use the word to mean ["great destruction."](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decimate)

### Decrease by an order of magnitude

In plain English, to divide something by ten is to decrease it by an order of magnitude.

Comment: You say that *decimation* (meaning the killing of every tenth soldier if a battle was lost) was 'almost completely abandoned 2000 years ago). It may surprise you to know that in WW One, the Italian army, fighting on the Allied side engaged just such a practice after losing battles with the Austrian army.

Comment: I would suggest that the word "decimate" has *already* shifted its meaning, except in instances when someone wishes to appear smarter than someone else and correct them to a historical and outdated meaning.  You could argue that even modern instances of the practice, as given in the example from @WS2, it would be just as appropriate to substitute "decimation" with "devastating punishment" - the devastation being the key element that is shared between the ancient and modern contexts for the word.

Comment: Note that *order of magnitude* only works in base-10 number systems. For example, if a culture or system uses a base-8 number system then an order of magnitude is 8 times, not 10 times. This is unlikely to be an issue, but it's still worth considering.

Comment: I know that is has happened in post-Roman times, which makes me sad. With more sophisticated legal mechanisms, however, such as _respondeat superior_, most military legal systems stopped using it as a _standard_ practice. But just as total war was universally condemned for centuries before the 1930s Spanish Civil War, that war was shockingly brutal. As long as there is war and oppression, someone will use decimation or other excessive practices. As the scorpion said to the frog, "It is in my nature."

Comment: If "increase its order of magnitude by one" is plain English, I'm afraid to see what you think is technical English.

Comment: Well, I meant that the first explanation of "order of magnitude" was written in plain English while the second explanation was more technical. True, "tenfold" is less complicated than order of magnitude, but 1) order of magnitude is used commonly enough that it is wise to know its meaning, and 2) it is possible to say, "increased by eight orders of magnitude," but the equivalent of tenfold would be one-hundred-billion-fold. Therefore, order of magnitude is a more useful phrase for expressing dramatic increases or decreases of any size in both linear and logarithmic scales.

Comment: I think the common meaning for "decimate" is a metaphor based on the original meaning; you don't get decimated unless things have gone very badly.

Comment: @talmu...  True...but in a base-8 number system, they're going to write "8" as "10", so the answer to the question is still the same.  An order of magnitude in base-8 is still written as "10".  http://cowbirdsinlove.com/43

Answer (score 16):

The single word meaning "multiply by ten" is *[decuple](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=decuple)* (it's like "triple" or "quadruple", but much rarer).

> *intr. & tr.v* To multiply or be multiplied by ten.

Etymology:

> [Middle English, from Old French, from Late Latin *decuplus* : Latin *decem,* ten; see **dekm̥** in the Appendix of Indo-European roots + Latin *-plus,* -fold; see **pel-**<sup>2</sup> in the Appendix of Indo-European roots.]

(American Heritage Dictionary)

As noted in the commments beneath Jimi Oke's answer, this word has various pronunciations:

- "DECK-yuple" (given by the AHD), i.e. something like /ˈdɛkjʊpl̩/, /ˈdɛkjəpl̩/, /ˈdɛkjupl̩/
- "de-KYOO-ple", i.e. something like /dɪˈkjupl̩/
- "de-CUP-ple", i.e. something like /dɪˈkʌpl̩/

I wrote an answer about the [pronunciation of "tuple"](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/373956/77227) that explains some of the reasons why.

Answer (score 2):

> Another Mathematical term is **denary**(ˈdiːnərɪ)  adj
>   ≡tenfold, ten-fold
>
> 1. (Mathematics) **calculated by tens**; based on ten;
> 2. containing ten parts; **tenfold**
>
>    3. numbered or proceeding [**by tens**](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/denary)

**(**[vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/denary)/[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/denary)**)**

Comment: That's only an adjective, though, and "denarize" might be confused with "[binarize](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/binarize)" (make binary) as in make base 10 instead of multiply by 10.

Comment: "denary" actually means the number is in base 10, not to multiply by 10, just like binary doesn't mean to multiply by 2