# Usage of "order of magnitude"

Tags: grammaticality

I wonder which of the following is correct.

> "A" outperforms "B" by two orders of magnitude.

and

> "A" outperforms "B" two orders of magnitude.

Personally I think both are correct but I am not sure. In an [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/37247/286877) to a related question, a sentence

> "The computer was orders of magnitude better than the abacus."

"orders of magnitude" is used like an adverb which makes me think that my second sentence is also correct.

Comment: "By", Matteo, and where's your research, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I have updated my question

Comment: "If values differ _by_ two orders of magnitude ..." [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_magnitude).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I consider the following to be correct...

> "A" outperforms "B" by two orders of magnitude.

'orders of magnitude' in the above sentence is a noun, a quantity being specified and '[by](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/by)' indicates the amount or size of a margin.

Similarly in the sentence

> "The computer was orders of magnitude better than the abacus."

Orders of Magnitude is not an adverb, but a noun specifying a quantity. E.g.

> X is 5 inches taller than Y

Replace '5 inches taller' with 'orders of magnitude better' and you would find no change in sentence structure.

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation of why you hold the view expressed in your response. Without such a clarification, readers have no basis for appraising the reliability of your opinion/judgment.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Explanation has been added. Do let me know if it's unclear.

Comment: Thank you for making the additional effort to clarify your thinking.

Answer (score 2):

You could say *A outperforms B*, but since you are adding the *two orders of magnitude* part, you should add the *by*.

Compare it with the word *exceed*, you could say *A exceeds B*, but when adding the latter part of your sentence (or any qualifier indicating *by* how much it exceeds), it is clearer when *by* is added.

> A exceeds B by 20 meters

Therefore, in your case it would have to be:

> **A outperforms B by two orders of magnitude**.

Comment: Thanks. +1 although I cannot upvote your answer due to low reputation.